# Reduce an NSString to lowercase, ascii alpha characters

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

How can I reduce an `NSString` to lowercase, ascii alpha characters (`/a-z/`)? Non-english alpha characters should be converted to ascii characters. Specifically, uppercase characters become lowercase (A → a), non-english characters become english characters (ñ → n), and all other characters are discarded.

For example: **"Västerås, Sweden"** becomes **"vasterassweden"**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert a string to an `NSData` containing bytes representing the string in a different encoding and allow for lossy conversion using `dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion`. Then you can just convert the `NSData` back to an `NSString`:

```
NSString *unicode = @"Västerås, Sweden";
NSString *ascii = [[NSString alloc]
                   initWithData:[unicode dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                      allowLossyConversion:YES
                                ]
                       encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                  ];
```

Result is "Vasteras, Sweden". Now there is a `lowercaseString` method etc. if you need to go further.

Edit:

Oops, missed the end of the question "and all other characters are discarded", you do wish to go further:

```
NSString *lower = [ascii lowercaseString];
NSString *letters = [[lower
                      componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]
                                                            invertedSet]
                                                           ]
                      componentsJoinedByString:@""
                    ];
```

That looks horrible (and a good argument to convert to a C-string and do it more directly), but it does the job: `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` returns an array of strings by treating the characters in the supplied set as the separators; `componentsJoinedByString:` joins an array of strings into a single string separated by the supplied string - and we've passed an empty joiner.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as following:

```
NSString *inputString = @"Västerås  ;; Swed   en    ";

NSLog(@"Input String %@",inputString);

inputString = [inputString lowercaseString]; // Lower case

inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]; //Whitespace

inputString = [[inputString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""]; //Punctuation

inputString = [[inputString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet decomposableCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""]; // non-english characters
```